# Group by week,month in mysql depending on php variable. If condition in group by

Tags: php, mysql, sql, dynamic-sql

I have a table, `prescription`, which the fields

- prescription_id
- description
- patient_id
- pres_date
- title

I know how to group by month, week or day. My question is, i want this to be dynamic. I have an interface in the UI where the user will select a category, month, day or week. Which i store in a variable $category. Is there any way to use an if condition in group by to see which category the user has selected, and return the sql query in that format.

For example, if the user selects month, in my sql query, i want it to return, group by month(pres_date), if the user selects day, i want sql to return group by day(pres_date).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need to use conditional logic.  Just do something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM prescription GROUP BY " . $category . "(pres_date)";
```

This way, your query gets built using one line.  Of course, make sure you validate the value of $category before you run the query.

Comment: unless `$category` is not a valid input. To check if it's a valid input, you will need to use some conditional logic ;)

Comment: beat me by 25 seconds... :) +1

Answer (score 1):

The code will be like this

```
if($_POST['select'] == 'month')
{
    $sql = "select * from table group by month(pres_date)";
}
else if($_POST['select'] == 'day')
{
    $sql = "select * from table group by day(pres_date)";
}
else
{
    $sql = "select * from table group by week(pres_date)";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to do this is in PHP, using if or switch statements:

```
$sql = "SELECT ... FROM ... ";
switch($category) {
    case 'month':
        $sql .= "GROUP BY month(pres_date)";
        break;
    case 'day':
        $sql .= "GROUP BY day(pres_date)";
        break;
    //... etc ...
    default:
        //bad category value; do some error handling
}

// now do $mysqli->query($sql) or $PDO->query($sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've already got yourself going on the right path. You should be able to build the base form of the query and then modify it depending on the value that they have selected. Try doing something in that fashion where you add `group by month(pres_date)` if they select month, etc.

Answer (score 0):

No need of multiple condition checking , get the selected option in variable and use it in sql query,

```
if(isset($_POST['selected_option']))
    $grp_option=$_POST['selected_option'];  
$sql = "SELECT .... GROUP BY".$grp_option."(pres_date)";
```